# Good Beginning Silverlight Game Resources?

Tags: silverlight

I am starting to learn Silverlight game programming, and was wondering if anyone knows of some good tutorials or resources to get started with. I'm just beginning, so guides that teach concepts thoroughly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Mike Snow's book on Silverlight game programming:

[http://www.amazon.com/Game-Programming-Silverlight-Michael-Snow/dp/1598639064/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247768957&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598639064)

It includes Silverlight 3 info too.  For general Silverlight programming I like Silverlight Unleashed.

Answer (score 1):

[Blue Rose Games](http://www.bluerosegames.com/brg/) is an online host of silverlight games and has a few tutorials on the subject

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything particularly special about writing games in Silverlight. I would just read any game resources I could get my hands on and then ask a particular question if I had trouble performing the same operations in Silverlight.